# Issue with if statement and conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written my code as shown below:

```
import random

diceOne = random.randint(1,6) 
diceTwo = random.randint(1,6)


print ('Playing Craps:') 
print('You have rolled a', diceOne ,'and a', diceTwo ) 
print ('for a total of', diceOne + diceTwo )


if diceOne == 3 and diceTwo == 3:
    print('This is called a Hard Six')
```

As can be seen, I've managed to get the condition working under the `if` statement. But the problem is I'm unable to figure out how to say that all variations that total six (other than two threes), will be labelled as "Easy Six" instead, e.g. 5 and 1, 2 and 4, etc.

I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I am a beginner when it comes to Python and coding in general, so please try to make the explanations rather simple.

Comment: `elif diceOne + diceTwo == 6:`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a nested if statement inside an if statement

```
if dice1+dice2==6:
     if dice1==3 and dice2==3:
          print('This is called a Hard Six')
     else:
          print('This is called Easy Six')
```

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe said, you can add an elif condition, which will indicate that your dices are not both equal to 3 (so your code does not enter in your if statement) but their total still equals six:

```
if diceOne == 3 and diceTwo == 3 :
    print('This is called a Hard Six')

elif (diceOne + diceTwo == 6) :
    print('This is called an Easy Six')
```

I can suggest you a pretty good tutorial for beginners in Python right here. It can look a bit slow sometimes but it's perfect to be comfortable with the very basics.
http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python